# Docker Volume to share PHP code between Container and Local for development using docker-compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm creating a docker image for a Laravel 10 development environment.

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
services:
  web:
    image: laravelfans/laravel
    container_name: laravel
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

At this moment, the image is created and the container is created. Typing localhost:8000 on browser, it shows me the Laravel home page.

Now, I want to map the Laravel file path inside the container (/var/www/laravel) to my local machine, so I can edit the code, using VSCode, for example. So I added the volume in docker-compose:

```
services:
  web:
    image: laravelfans/laravel
    container_name: laravel
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/laravel/
```

I've already tried some variations, like `'./src/':'/var/www/laravel/'`, or removing the ending bars like: `'./src':'/var/www/laravel'`. But when the image is recreated, the container exit(1) right after the startup.

To create the image and start the container, I'm using the following:
`docker compose create`
`docker compose up -d`

What am I missing? Ty.

Comment: is your code really under `src`? That doesn't sound like a typical Laravel project

Comment: You cannot share FROM container. Only INTO container.

Comment: post your code structure from root..

Comment: ./src is where I want it to be in my local machine. The Laravel project is created by the container, in the /var/www/laravel folder.

Comment: @Maksim , I was thinking about a two way sharing. Edit the code in localmachine, and it affects the container. The laravelfans/laravel docker image creates the Laravel structure itself, so I needed it to, first, copy from container, and after that, the two way. ty.